# how to open a video from the gallery into my app?

Tags: android

**edit :
I solved it by adding this line :**

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
```

I am trying to start a video from my gallery into my MQ Player media app as shown here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6nFL.jpg

I add this to my manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.video.ExoplayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MQPlayer"
            android:exported="true">
           

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

but i get null on the `intent.getData()`
what should I do I need to know the **URI** of the video to start playing it into my app